# How to convert list like value in each row into pure value in python dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a value that looks as belows

```
colA    desired
[0]       0
[3, 1]    3,1
[3, 1, 2] 3,1,2
[3, 1]    3,1
```

The type for colA is object.
Is there a way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without the lambda as that will be slower for larger data sets, you can simply cast the list to a string type then strip unwanted characters.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'colA':[[0], [3,1],[3,1,2],[3,1]]})
df['desired'] = df.colA.astype(str).str.replace('\[|\]|\'', '')
df
```

Output:

```
colA            desired
0   [0]         0
1   [3, 1]      3, 1
2   [3, 1, 2]   3, 1, 2
3   [3, 1]      3, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'colA':[[0], [3,1],[3,1,2],[3,1], [4]]})
df['desired'] = df['colA'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
        colA desired
0        [0]       0
1     [3, 1]     3,1
2  [3, 1, 2]   3,1,2
3     [3, 1]     3,1
4        [4]       4
```

If colA is obj:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'colA':["[0]", "[3,1]","[3,1,2]","[3,1]", "[4]"]})
df['desired'] = df['colA'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, literal_eval(x))))
```

Comment: if the input is [4], it returns [,4,]

Comment: Working fine for me. Check my edited answer, it outputs `4` for me

Comment: Check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.replace`:

```
df['desired'] = df['colA'].str.replace(r'[][]', '', regex=True)
```

Prints:

```
        colA  desired
0        [0]        0
1     [3, 1]     3, 1
2  [3, 1, 2]  3, 1, 2
3     [3, 1]     3, 1
```

You can use the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHRBDR/1) to play with it.